# What is the Correct way to update callback references when Android Activity's callbacks go null after an orientation change

Tags: android, android-activity, callback

I have an Activity which implements a listener. My concern is that the
activity can get re-created and the callback will then have a reference
to an object that is null.

This means we must update the controller with a new reference that references
the newly created activity.

> What pattern is best to use even if the callbacks are async? 
>   Is there perhaps a safe way to update the controllers reference in a thread > safe way.

**OR**

> Should one rather use a Headless fragment and use the onAttach method get the
>   updated reference.

**OR**

> Should one rather not use these patterns and use a Handler for
>   all your callbacks?

I suspect that my updateListener method will not work in all cases e.g.

1) init is busy and is just about to call the callback, line marked with
*10*

2) the activity gets recreated and updates the controller with
a new reference but the updateListener method is blocked because the callback is about to take place.

3) the callback executes and fails as the listener reference variable is stale.

```
public class Controller {

     UserActionListener listener
     static Controller instance;

     public static synchronized Controller getInstance(UserActionListener listener) {
         if (instance == null) {
           instance = new Controller();
         } 
         this.listener = listener;
         return instance;
      }

     private Controller() {
        //empty, enforce getInstance
     }

     private init() {
         // do some very long running operation in a separate thread.
         //.... on completion we update the UI
         synchronized(Controller.class) {
         /*10*/   listener.handle("SHOW DIALOG");
         }
     }

     public void updateListener(UserActionListener listener) {
        synchronized(Controller.class) {
           this.listener = listener;
        }
     }



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements UserActionListener {

static Controller controller;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    controller = Controller.getInstance(this);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
       //do not run on re-create 
       controller.init();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostResume() {
    super.onPostResume();
    controller.updateListener(this);
}

@Override
public void handleAction(String userAction) {

    switch (userAction) {

       case "SHOW DIALOG" :
             Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Hello",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

the direct answer to your question is a simple subscription pattern.
on the activity you call:

```
@Override
public void onStart(){
   controller.updateListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop(){
   controller.updateListener(null);
}
```

and inside the controller check for null before calling anything on the listener.
But there's a fundamental flaw on the logic.

With the following code:

```
static Controller controller;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    controller = new Controller(this);
}
```

the static controller having a reference to the activity is leaking the activity, avoiding it to be garbage collected.

also, even thou the controller is static, you're creating a new one every time the activity is created, also inside the controller `init()` you have the following:

```
   // do some very long running operation
   //....
```

that means this very long running operation is:

- running in the UI thread. This will block your app initialisation, the user will think it's broken and the system will probably show a message to the user asking to close it.
- there's nothing to guarantee that your process won't be killed either by the user or by the system before the "very long operation" finishes. If you want to run a long operation you **MUST** user a `Service` instead.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I have updated my question to be more correct the way I intended but neglected to do. Can you please look at the changes I made.

Comment: your edit is less worse, but I suggest to re-read my answer. use `start/stop` to set/reset listener. And move any long running operations to a Service,  because without the activity the system might decide to kill the VM your controller is running and it will not finish its operation.

Comment: this is not actual code, it represents what the problem is.  My problem is the REFERENCE that can be null. The long running task is not a problem for me as it is actually handled by an SDK which does the actual hard work. The SDK will report back when it is done, and then when I need to update the UI is the actual problem. What do I do when the reference is null? 
Loop until it is not null does not sound like an option.

Comment: I agree the reference should be a WeakReference. Should I update the question to use a weakReference?

Comment: I wouldn't use `WeakReference` I would use `start/stop` as described in my answer. If it's `null` you can either ignore, because the activity is dead, and nobody cares about the result any more, or remember the result inside controller, and the moment some listener gets registered, immediately call `.handle` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Very sample, Use `WeakReference` to activity